# How to match optional parameter in url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Is it possible to use optional parameter for url?
For example path `fruits/:id` will match the same component if parameter `id` is not passed;

```
<Route path="/fruits/:id">
  <Fruits />
</Route>
```

At the moment to implement it I need to declare two routes `fruits:/id` and `/fruites/` to match the same component.

```
<Route path="/fruits/:id">
  <Fruits />
</Route>

<Route path="/fruits/">
  <Fruits />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define route like this

```
<Route path="/fruits/:id?">
```

this will work for both /fruits and /fruits/1

Answer (score 0):

You're using react-router so you don't have to worry about it. React router will match both /fruits and /fruits/1 using this code.

```
<Route path="/fruits/:id">
  <Fruits />
</Route>
```